# How do I resize Android FloatingButton?

Tags: android

XML file code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fabbutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Java file code:

```
FloatingActionButton ehkelebutton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.ehkelebutton);
ImageView ehkele1 = new ImageView(this);
ehkele1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ehkelehublogo);
ImageView ehkele2 = new ImageView(this);
ehkele2.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
ImageView ehkele3 = new ImageView(this);
ehkele3.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
ImageView ehkele4 = new ImageView(this);
ehkele4.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
SubActionButton.Builder itemBuilder = new SubActionButton.Builder(this);
SubActionButton button1 = itemBuilder.setContentView(ehkele1).build();
SubActionButton button2 = itemBuilder.setContentView(ehkele2).build();
SubActionButton button3 = itemBuilder.setContentView(ehkele3).build();
SubActionButton button4 = itemBuilder.setContentView(ehkele4).build();
FloatingActionMenu actionMenu = new FloatingActionMenu.Builder(this)
        .addSubActionView(button1)
        .addSubActionView(button2)
        .addSubActionView(button3)
        .addSubActionView(button4)
        .attachTo(ehkelebutton)
        .build();
```

> **Here is a photo of what I am trying to resize:**

[image: IMAGE PREVIEW]

Comment: u can edit lib 
or
change drawable size 
ex change ic_lanchur size

Answer (score 0):

Set the button type (normal or mini) via the fab_type xml attribute

```
fab:fab_type="mini"
```

or
java code

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setType(FloatingActionButton.TYPE_MINI);
```

More detail refer [FloatingActionButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html)

Comment: The submitter is using the Android Support Library FAB, so I edited your link to match the proper documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the code of FAB, it is extending ImageButton.

So create an ImageButton, give it elevation, make drawable to create a circle and set that as background and add a src to the ImageButton.